# Give permissions from super user process in mkfifo

Tags: c, linux, mkfifo

I need to create a pipe using `mkfifo()` from a super user process, that pipe must be writable from a process not super user.

Reader:

```
int main () {
  char *myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
  int buf;
  mkfifo(myfifo, 0777); //problem here

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(myfifo,"r");
  if ( fp == NULL) {
    unlink(myfifo);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("received: %d\n",buf);

  fclose(fp);
  unlink(myfifo);
  return 0;
}
```

Writer:

```
int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  char *myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

  fp = fopen(myfifo,"w");
  if ( fp == NULL)
    return -1;

  fprintf(fp, "%d ", 2);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I call `./writer` and `sudo ./reader`.

When my writer try to write in the pipe that return a segmentation fault. And if I look in `/tmp/myfifo` I found that permissions `prwxr-xr-x`, but I want `prw-rw-rw-`.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs because you don't check if `fopen()` did open the file, it's very likely that the permissions are the cause, but it's very bad practice not to check for `fp == NULL`.

Comment: GDB is your friend! A segfault *always* indicates a programming error.

Comment: You are right, but this is an example, now I'll modify it.
The segmentation fault become also if I check that `fp != NULL ` :)

Comment: now your check is wrong :-) it has to be `if( fp == NULL ) return -1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writer is segfaulting because you are opening it for writing, but do not have permissions to write to it. Hence `fp` will be `NULL`, and your `fprintf` fails.

The reason for your FIFO having incorrect permissions is probably because your `umask` is `022`, which means those bits are being cleared from the mask you send to `mkfifo`. This will result in the permissions you see. To fix this, either change your `umask` using the `umask` call, or explicitly set permissions with `chmod`.

But do you really want your FIFO to be executable?

Comment: No, I don't need that my FIFO is executable, but I was hopeless when I give the executable permission. :P